# Get local time from UTC after setting time manually to moment object

Tags: momentjs

I have a UTC string/number (eg. 1510678360)
When converted to moment object, it gets converted to that specific date and time, as expected.

```
var momentObj = moment(1510678360, 'x');
console.log(momentObj); // Tuesday, November 14, 2017 4:52:40 PM GMT
```

I tried to set a particular time to that object, and that time got updated as expected, as well.

```
momentObj = momentObj.set({h:22, m:30});
console.log(momentObj); // Tuesday, November 14, 2017 10:30:00 PM
```

When I convert the `momentObj` to the local timezone, and when I try to get the `hour` or `minute`, then the expected date and time is not been displayed.

```
var momentObj = moment(1510678360, 'x');
momentObj = momentObj.set({h:22, m:30});
momentObj = moment(momentObj).tz(moment.tz.guess);
// expected: Wednesday, November 15, 2017 4:00:00 AM GMT+05:30
console.log(momentObj.get('hour')); // 22 instead of 4  
console.log(momentObj.get('minute')); // 30 instead of 00
```

Instead, the time that I just added is what is getting displayed. The time that I tried to add, got included only after the timezone conversion but I want that addition to happen before the conversion.

Comment: Use [moment.utc()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

Comment: I'm not facing issue in the first two steps. Only when I get the object's time, then it is giving me the exact time that I added to the object but with the next date. i.e. `4:30` as per my example.

Comment: Don't log a moment object directly.  Format it first.  Otherwise you're just looking at internal fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question is to use moment.utc()
suggested in the `comments` section for the question.